# How many two-qubit controlled gates do you need to simulate any CU gates where U is a diagonal matrix?

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

Assuming we have n qubit, the first qubit is a control qubit, and the rest are the targets of $U$.

If $U$ is a diagonal matrix, is there any theory to find the minimum number of two-qubit controlled gates to simulate CU (controlled-U)?

Comment: Is $U$ a single-qubit gate? And which universal set of gates are you willing to use?

Comment: @TristanNemoz i just edited my question for more details, please check it out.

Comment: I'm quite sure that this can't be done in less than $O\left(2^n\right)$ gates because each rotation in $U$ is essentially independent from the $2^n-1$ others, but would like to be proven wrong! Plus, this argument is only about the total number of gates, not the depth or the number of two-qubit gates

Comment: Forget about making a controlled-diagonal. Just ask what the complexity of making an arbitrary diagonal matrix is. This must essentially be the same: controlled-diagonals are also diagonal, while using the control qubit as $|1\rangle$ immediately gives you a construction of the diagonal.

Comment: @DaftWullie thank you, but i didn't know how to construct a diagonal matrix. Can you please show me how.

Comment: Would you be able to construct a gate which is all 1s on the diagonal, except for the last entry, which is $e^{i\theta}$? From there, can you change your circuit so that the $e^{i\theta}$ can be on whichever diagonal element you choose? Can you then combine those to make any diagonal unitary you want?

Answer (score 1):

As @DaftWullie said in the comments the matrix of a controlled diagonal gate is itself a diagonal matrix. So we need only consider how many two qubit controlled gates are requried to synthesise a diagonal unitary matrix.

This is discussed in a well cited paper by Shende, Bullock and Markov entitled [Synthesis of Quantum Logic Circuits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0406176.pdf). The paper discusses how to synthesise unitary operators as well as prepare arbitary quantum states. The results of the paper are achieved with the use of "multiplexor" operations, a useful generalisation of a multicontrolled gate introduced in section 3 by the authors.

Theres a lot of ground covered in the paper so I'd encourage you to read it for the details. Decomposition of diagonal matrices $\Delta$ is discussed in theorem 7.

In theorem 7 of the paper it is shown that a general diagonal gate $\Delta$ acting over $k+1$ qubits is equivalent to another diagonal matrix acting over $k$ qubits followed by a multiplexed-Rz operation controlled by $k$ qubits.

I think you can use theorem 8 from the paper to then decompose the multiplexed-Rz in terms of CNOT gates. It takes $\mathcal{O}(2^k)$ CNOT gates to do this.

Comparing this to the cost of synthesising an arbitrary unitary (which takes $\mathcal{O}(4^k)$ CNOT gates) it seems that synthesising diagonal unitaries is easier than the general case although its still exponential in the number of qubits. The paper is reasonably old so I'm not sure if an improved method is known.

I've definetly glossed over some details in this answer but hopefully this helps.

This decomposition method is used the [DiagonalBox](https://cqcl.github.io/tket/pytket/api/circuit.html#pytket.circuit.DiagonalBox) construction in the pytket SDK.

Comment: I realise this answer is a bit incomplete as it stands. I can edit to fill in the gaps.